# How to schedule AWS Lambda to run exactly at 12:00:00 am (second-level precision)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a use case where I need to run a function **daily at 12:00:00 am**. My Python code takes 3-4 seconds to initialize and 3 seconds to execute. It would still be fine if my function is triggered within 1 second after 12:00:00 am, but I can't do it with AWS Lambda triggered by AWS CloudWatch.

I have created a AWS Lambda function and it's being triggered every 11:59 pm using AWS CloudWatch Events because it [does not provide second level precision](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html). So, it's *wasting computing time averaging between 15 - 45 seconds* after initializing just to sleep until 12:00:00 am.

Although the price is still quite low, but I just felt annoyed that the **majority (>75%) of the computing time taken is used to Sleep**. Anyone else has a better idea?

Comment: Your current process seems to be the best way to do it. The cost of the Lambda function for that minute is minor compared to your apparent desire for such accuracy.

Comment: I see, thanks for your input. Just trying to see if I missed anything.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried scheduling lambda execution using cron expression?

This expression 0 0 * * ? * would run your lambda every day at midnight GMT.
Adjust accordingly to your time zone.

[image: scheduling lambda with cron expression]

Comment: According to AWS documentation (and tried it myself) it does not run exactly at the 0th second, which is 12:00:00 am.